# Magento v1.9.0.1 - Most Viewed Products Report only showing top 5?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

I have been looking for a quick fix on the net to get the Most Viewed Products report to show top 100 products viewed, instead of only top 5 viewed. Can't seem to find anything on the net to solve this.

Comment: Matt, are  you working backend ya frontend??

Comment: You did not clarify your question (frontend or backend) so you got answers for frontend & backend below. Please be more specific next time and set the answer that helped you as "accepted".

Answer (score 3):

Login to Admin and go to `System > Configuration > Catalog (Left Side) > Recently Viewed/Compared Products`

Their See the value `Default Recently Viewed Products Count` and if it is 5 change what ever you want.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82604/product-list-page-sort-by-most-view-can-we-sort-this-by-page-views-hits

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Report/Product/Viewed/Collection.php

Copy the file to app/code/local/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Report/Product/Viewed/Collection.php

Change this line (#39):

```
protected $_ratingLimit        = 5;
```

to 
    protected $_ratingLimit        = 100;

Comment: Copying whole files to app/code/local is not considered best pracitse. It's better to make a proper rewrite in this case.