# Product List Page Sort by Most View ( can we sort this by page views/hits)

Tags: product-list, sorting

I Want To Sort By Product Listing Page using Most View. Most View means highest Product visited Display First. means highest show product to Lowest
Product. What Can Change i Don't Understand. Can You Give any Idea about that.

This want to create in select box sort by MOST VIEW

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Getting some code it's work proper but if product not display any time then it can be display in product list.

You Just want to orverride app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php

paste in code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php

`public function getAvailableOrders()`in this function 
add this code

```
 $this->addOrderToAvailableOrders('mostviewd', 'MOST POPULAR');
        return $this->_availableOrder;\\you can add this code here
```

and `public function setCollection($collection)` this function add this type code after

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {


 if($this->getCurrentOrder()=='mostviewd') {
              $this->_collection->getSelect()->
joinInner('report_event AS _table_views',
' _table_views.object_id = e.entity_id',
'COUNT(_table_views.event_id) AS views')->
group('e.entity_id')->order('views DESC');


            }
```

try this it's Working But it can not display who product never seen any time

Link Most View [Link Most View](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2015/09/magento-category-product-listing-sort-by-show-most-viewed-products.html)

Comment: Most viewed product sorting is working fine but in the toolbar getting only 1 product and also pagination is not displayed. Can anyone who can help to solve the issue. 
Appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create the file

> app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Mostviewed.php

Then add the following code:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->addViewsCount();
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

        $products->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);
        $this->setProductCollection($products);
    } }
```

After this, create another file:

> app/design/frontend/default/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml

with following code:

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class=" most_viewed">
<div class="mv_title"><?php echo $this->__('These Products Are Popular Right Now!') ?></div>
<?php $_collectionSize = 5;//count($_products->getItems()); echo $_collectionSize; ?>
<ul class="products-grid" id="products-grid-table">
<?php $i=1; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
    <li id="td_<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if($i%5==0 or $i==$_collectionSize){echo 'class="last"';} ?> >
        <div id="cont_<?php echo $i;?>">        
            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
            </a>
            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h3>
            <div class="a-center">                        
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability"><span class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                    <li class="last"><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php $i++; endforeach; $kol = $_collectionSize; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now, to display it, use this code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_mostviewed" template="catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml"}}
```

And there you could see the most viewed products.

---

If you want, you could display best selling options with these codes:

> app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Bestseller.php

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Bestseller extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); // most best sellers on top
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

        $products->setPageSize(3)->setCurPage(1);
        $this->setProductCollection($products);
    }
}
```

And

> App/design/frontend/default/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/bestseller.phtml

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Best Seller Products') ?></h2>
</div>
<?php $_collectionSize = count($_products->getItems()) ?>
<table class="products-grid" id="products-grid-table">
<?php $i=1; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i%1!==0): ?>
    <tr>
    <?php endif ?>
        <td id="td_<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if($i%3==0 or $i==$_collectionSize){echo 'class="last"';} ?> >
        <?php contentBlock('top') ?>
        <div id="cont_<?php echo $i;?>">
            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h3>
            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(122, 109); ?>" width="122" height="109" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
            </a>
            <div class="a-center">                        
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability"><span class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <li class="last"><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php if($_product->getevent_date()) {echo $_product->getevent_date();} ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <?php if ($i%3==0 or $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
   </tr>
    <?php endif ?>
  <?php $i++; endforeach; $kol = $_collectionSize; ?>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And to display the most selling products:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_bestseller" template="catalog/product/bestseller.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Please check Question Again @ntzz i am give proper image want i want.