# Get Most view products of current product categories in product detail page(view.phtml) in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

I want to create you may also interested Section in product detail page.
this section create most view product of current product of categories.
means view.phtml file product of categories of most view product.

```
 $categories = $_product->getCategoryCollection()
                          ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $catIds[] = $category->getID();

                }
```

print_r(catIds);

here i am get category 17,31. i can not undestand how to get 
this category most view product display here.

How to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $category_ids = $_product->getCategoryIds();   
     $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $product_id))
            ->addViewsCount()
            ->joinField('category_id',
            'catalog/category_product',
            'category_id',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            null,
            'left'
        )
            //->addAttributeToFilter('category_ids',array('finset'=>$category_ids))
            //->addCategoryFilter($category)
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            //
            ->setPageSize(4)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $category_ids ));

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
foreach($products as $_products )
        {
         //you code
        }
```

**

> main issue is that i have to remove or not display current product in
>   this. then which filter use. if go to xyz product detail page then xyz
>   is most view product it will display here. but i can not display this
>   product in you may also interested Section. What I do Any Suggestion.

**

Comment: http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2015/09/magento-get-most-view-products-of-current-prodcut-categories-detail-page.html

Answer (score 1):

Here Is possible solution.I am not sure but it should work

```
// write code in view.phtml 
    $categoryId = $_product->getCategoryIds(); 
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty() //total number of quantities ordered
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*') //get all attributes
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc') //most ordered quantity products first
        ->addCategoryFilter($category);

        foreach($products as $_products )
        {
         //you code
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$category_ids = $_product->getCategoryIds(); 

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_ids',array('finset'=>$category_ids))
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->addViewsCount()

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

foreach($products as $product){
    echo $product->getName();
    echo $product->getPrice();
}
```

Comment: Hello how to get product detail like product name,price product detail can you please tell me?

Comment: see my updated code

Comment: Thanks. Can You Please Same type Work for magento sort product check this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82604/product-list-page-sort-by-most-view-can-we-sort-this-by-page-views-hits

Comment: if you can help then please tell me

Comment: Sorry i am checking data but it's not filter data using category.